# parsing return value out of a python script run in a bash script

Tags: bash, google-apps

I'm trying to write a code to extract return values from Google's GAM script.

I've written a program to see how values are returned and hopefully interact with them, but I haven't had much luck. Here's what the test code looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
    gam_test(){
             OAUTHFILE=oauth.txt
            local gtestout=`~/gam/gam.py info user "$email" > test`
    }
    fname="April"
    lname="O'Neil"
    letter1=${fname:0:1}
    letter2=${lname:0:1}
    error_out="Error: 1301 - Entity AOkccp30@ga4edu.org Does Not Exist"
    concatemail=$letter1$letter2"kccp30@ga4edu.org"
    fullemail="AOkccp30@ga4edu.org"
    email=$fullemail
    gam_test
    sleep 5
    echo "---------"
    sleep 3
    echo $gtestout
    echo "---------"
    if [ "$error_out" -eq `gam_test` ]
            then
                    echo "Test 1 Success!! They are the same when you feed it emails!"
            else
                    echo "TEST 1 FAIL! WHAT DID YOU DO!?"
                    echo $error_out"/...test..../"
                    echo $gam_test"/....gam_test.../"
            fi
    email=$concatemail
    gtestout=$(python ~/gam/gam.py info user "$email" &)
    echo "---------"
    sleep 3
    echo $gtestout
    echo "---------"
    if [ "$error_out" == "$gtestout" ]
            then
                    echo "Test 2 Success!! They are the same when the program generates emails!"
            else
                    echo "TEST 2 FAIL! WHAT DID YOU DO!?"
```

I've tried a few other methods but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Since you're redirecting the output to the `test` file, nothing will be put in the variable `$gtestout`.

Comment: `-eq` is only for comparing numbers, use `=` for strings. And quote the strings if they can contain whitespace.

Comment: The test file isn't getting the program response, but I'll take the line out.